# How to solve this error in pimcore CMS

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore

Fatal error: Call to a member function getGoals() on a non-object

controller:

```
{  $newsList = new Object\homepage\Listing(); }
```

view:

```
{<?= homepage->getGoals(); ?>}
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail of the code you are using here? Either `homepage` is not defined in the view or you really just forgot to add the `$` in front of the variable name, but with the provided code this is pretty much impossible to tell

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing the wrong way, because you don't understand the fundamental of MVC. 
I believe that you doon't want to get the list of the Homepage objects.

There are several ways to check your code:
1. Be sure that you have any Object with field "Goals"
2. Use documentation to get list of objects

For example.

Controller:

```
// get a list of news objects
        $newsList = new Object\News\Listing();
        $this->view->news = $newsList ;
```

View:

```
<?=$this->news->getName()?>
```

or

```
<?=$this->news->getGoal()?>
```

if you create this field.